# Apollo with redux-persist

Tags: react-native, react-redux, apollo, react-apollo

I integrated [**react-apollo**](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo) for fetching data from my GraphQL server into my react native application. I use **redux-perist** for persisting and rehydrating the redux store.

But I don't know how to rehydrate my apollo state.

Anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `autoRehydrate` feature of `redux-persist`. It will asyncronously run an action with type `REHYDRATE` that will rehydrate all stores unless you blacklist them.

If you try to execute a query that was previously executed, Apollo will check your Redux store first and you should see an `APOLLO_QUERY_RESULT_CLIENT` action execute (meaning it's returning from the client store instead of querying the server). You can modify the [`fetchPolicy`](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#FetchPolicy) to specify how the query gets its data (network only, cache first, etc.)

Here's a basic setup:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({ uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' });

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: networkInterface,
});

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    apollo: client.reducer(),
  }),
  {}, // initial state
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(client.middleware()),
    autoRehydrate(),
  ),
);

// persistent storage
persistStore(store, {
  storage: AsyncStorage, // or whatever storage you want
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
        <YourApp />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @srtucker22 !! My problem was I used devTools(), and then autoRehydrate (). For some strange reason this does not work, I have to do autoRehydrate () first and then devTools () .. and now it works!

Comment: @Carol Bless you. Your solution just brought 3 days of nail biting, and hair pulling, to an end. Placing `autoRehydrate()` before `(typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ !== 'undefined' || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : (f) => f,` resolved data being persisted after a page reload.